# Writing vertically in an SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to write vertically in SSRS?  For example I want to show page no. vertically on the right hand side of the report.

Thanks 
Furqan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the TextBox you want to write vertically, and open the properties grid by pressing F4. Change the WritingMode to "vertical". Take care that the carret is not active, otherwise, the option is not visible.